# Python pandas.DataFrame.to_dict with custom column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run df.to_dict('records') on my dataframe, I get this:

```
    {'country_name': 'Australia', 'count': 55},
    {'country_name': 'Brunei Darussalam', 'count': 90},
    {'country_name': 'Cambodia', 'count': 234}
```

However, this is what I want:

```
    {'name': 'Australia', 'y': 55},
    {'name': 'Brunei Darussalam', 'y': 90},
    {'name': 'Cambodia', 'y': 234}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please post your code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you doing the `to_dict`, `rename` it

```
df.rename(columns={'country_name':'name','count':'y'}).to_dict('records')
```

Comment: @Pavitran I think using the name directly  are create less confusion , if you do need , doing `df1=df,iloc[:,[1,2]]; df1.columns=['name','y'];df1.to_dict('records') `

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code seems to suit my needs:


`df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'name', df.columns[1]:'y'}).to_dict('records')}`